# Any bright ideas or plugins to recommend? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to make a WP MU so only subscribers that is given access can view certain categories and this is to be different subscribers for different categories (or posts)( i mean to be picked up which can for every category or post).
For example:
-Category 1 can be viewed by:
*subscriber 2
*subscriber 6
*subscriber 11
-Category 2 can be viewed by:
*subscriber 11
*subscriber 13

Hope you got what I mean.
:) Thanks in advance, I'm thinking this for a week now but can't put my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://www.s2member.com/